# let A be an n x n matrix...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If the kernel of A only has the zero vector, then how can I use this piece of information to prove that A is non-singular? what connection is there between the kernel of A and the singularity of the matrix?

Comment: If the kernel is trivial then $\lambda=0$ is not en eigenvalue then ...

Comment: If $A$ has a trivial kernel ($\ker A = \{0 \}$), then $Ax = 0$ has only the trivial solution so $A$ is invertible. (See the [invertible matrix theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If kernel of a square matrix A has only zero vector it means that $$Ax=0\iff x=0$$ that is precisely (one of) the definition of **not singular matrix**.

Indeed in such case $\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalues for $A$ and thus $det(A)\neq0$.

Another way to see is: since no trivial combination of columns vectors lead to zero, colummn vectors are linearly independent thus A is not singular.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $Ax=Ay$. Then $A(x-y)=0$, but the kernel of $A$ is trivial, so $x=y$. Thus, the linear map represented by $A$ is injective. By the Rank-Nullity theorem, the map is also is surjective, hence it is bijective and has an inverse.